# Link that only select a ng-tab

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

I have a link:

```
<a routerLink="./" (click)="t.select('categories-settings')">
```

that I use only to select a [ng-tab](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/tabs).

Thing is with routerLink, it will refresh page, and without routerlink, it will remove the link.

In the example, a button is used, not a link.

How should I do?

Answer (score 0):

If its Just to show a link then remove the routerLink and add small css to it just change the cursor: pointer; and if you want change color too on hover.
Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Add a button inside the `a` tag:

```
<a routerLink="./">
   <button (click)="t.select('categories-settings')">Click Me</button>
</a>
```